# Ruby shift and slice issue with Recursion

Tags: ruby

Can someone explains to me why Array slice or shift returns different results than `args -= [args.frist]`

I want to output `[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3], []]`.

```
def run(args=[1,2,3],results=[])  
  results << args  
  return results if args.size < 1  
  args -= [args.first]  
  run(args,results)
end
```

VS.

```
def run(args=[1,2,3],results=[])
   results << args
   return results if args.size < 1
   args.shift
   run(args,results)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is **pass-by-value**. But the objects are actually the references. Let me explain. When you do:

```
s = 'abc'
s1 = s
s1.gsub! /a/, 'A'
puts s
# ⇒ 'Abc'
```

Unless you `dup` an object, all the references will be point to the same, say, memory block. That’s why in you second example `args` is modified not only itself, but inside the `results` array.

The line

```
args -= [args.first]
```

actually doesn’t change the array given as parameter, though. It declares new local variable and changes it. References to already put into `results` values remain as they were.

```
run args.dup.shift, result
```

will do the trick.

Comment: this explains a lot. I have spent too much time trying to figure out why the result is not in-sync.

Answer (score 0):

Because all the `args` are referencing the same array.

To avoid it, don't modify `args`.

Instead, make a copy:

```
def run(args=[1,2,3],results=[])
  results << args
  return results if args.size < 1
  run(args[1..-1], results)
end
```